# How do I remove a complete nether tower?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have recently built a nether reactor next to my house and a ton of obsidian spawned messing up my beautiful house and not letting me sleep. Please help!I also have 3 diamond picks and a ton of TNT which I know won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the newest version of Minecraft PE. [Obsidian forming from Nether Reactors was a bug that was fixed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#0.6.0).

If you're talking about [Glowing Obsidian](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowing_obsidian) this should be able to be broken with a Diamond Pickaxe (the same is the case with regular Obsidian, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Nether towers are made out of nether 
which break really easily and can be blown
up by TNT 
They are not made up of obsidian